# Is there a way to flip a Smart TV so the application displaying is in vertical?

Tags: css, tizen, smart-tv

I'm coding an SmartTv app with Tizen and i need that the display info its on vertical, meaning that the TV is not horizontal but vertical, so is there a way to code so when the app launches it doesn't launch's horizontally but vertically like the TV position?

I've already tried searching online for a way buy no useful material

Answer (score 1):

You can add to config.xml screen-orientation:

```
<tizen:setting screen-orientation="portrait"/>
```

However, this will not rotate the playback.

You can find some documentation here:
[Configuring Applications](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/configuring-your-app/configuration-editor?langredirect=1)